# Changing Ownership: "Operation not permitted" - even as root!

Tags: permissions, chown

I am trying to help a user solve an issue with a bootable USB drive, but there seems to be a file whose ownership cannot be edited. I thought it would have been possible with:

```
sudo chown user:user ldlinux.sys
```

When that is executed, however, terminal gives this error:

```
Operation not permitted
```

The extended chat I had with the user can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674997/live-usb-does-not-boot-after-hard-reset-messed-with-file-permissions/675007?noredirect=1#comment977860_675007).

Comment: Maybe checking ACLs is an option? I commented on the original question and asked for the output of `getfacl ldlinux.sys`

Comment: I think the USB is mounted read-only. Ask OP to check mount options via `mount`.

Comment: AFAIK it is (users:username) not just the user

Comment: users:username ?? it is user:group

Comment: Check your `id`. This error can appear if your user by some reason was assigned to another group. In normal situation `id` should look like this `uid=1000(username) gid=1000(username) groups=1000(username)`.
You can check and change it in `/etc/passwd` file as well.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Probably the file has the immutable flag set in its extended attributes:

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % touch immutable
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % sudo chown root:root immutable
[sudo] password for user:
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % sudo chattr +i immutable
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % lsattr immutable
----i--------e-- immutable
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % sudo chown user:user immutable
chown: changing ownership of 'immutable': Operation not permitted
```

To fix this, just run `sudo chattr -i file`:

```
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % sudo chattr -i immutable
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % lsattr immutable
-------------e-- immutable
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp % sudo chown user:user immutable
user@user-X550CL ~/tmp %
```

Comment: I get: chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on 64GB, while trying this on a usb thumb drive at /media/

Comment: For me, the "a" (Append only) flag was the problem. `sudo chattr -a fileName` solved the problem.

Comment: +1, but fails for some files (not just symlinks), even running as root `sudo chattr -i` returning `chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags.`

Comment: My USB has `msdos` filesystem.  Found this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552121/chattr-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-while-reading-flags  so I went ahead and reformatted as ext4 per https://askubuntu.com/questions/149984/formatting-usb-flash-memory-for-ubuntu-ext4

Comment: You get the `Operation not supported` error when trying to mount a Windows filesystem (exFat/NTFS) with incorrect mount options. You can either reformat your drive to ext4, or simply change the mount options with this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/956072/612853

Comment: Thanks kos, this solved it for me just now.. But, man chattr doesn't even list -i as an option! So, thanks again.