# file owner cannot chmod file, report operation not permitted

Tags: chmod, chown

1. use root copy or create a file `a.out`
2. `chown user:user a.out`, change `a.out` owner to user
3. now change to user, `su user`
4. use user to chmod a.out, `chmod 755 a.out`
5. Ok, problem is here. step 4 will output : `chmod: ./a.out: Operation not permitted`

I run these step on SUSE, it's work.
And chmod can use by file owner or root. So, i think this maybe a bug on Ubuntu.
Anyone know this?

Comment: "So, i think this maybe a bug on Ubuntu." doubt it. More likely the directory above where you did this? Or immutable flag? Or ACL.

Comment: Could not reproduce

Answer (score 3):

Check to see if the file is set as [immutable](https://www.tecmint.com/chattr-command-examples/).

```
root@hostname:/tmp# lsattr ./a.out
----i--------e-- a.out
```

That i means the file is immutable and cannot be changed. You have to use `chattr -i ./a.out` to clear the flag, and then `+i` to re-enable after making changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the file is not set as immutable, as mentioned here:

[Changing Ownership: "Operation not permitted" - even as root!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675296/changing-ownership-operation-not-permitted-even-as-root)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the current directory is write allowed for your user.

```
ls -laF
```

and see what are permissions for . directory.

Comment: . directory is user, but .. is root

Comment: Can you post output of the command ? And also output of "lsattr a.out"