# How to delete a swap file in Ubuntu?

Tags: sudo, swap

I created a swap file in Ubuntu by [following this process](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04), but I no longer need it, so I would like to delete it.

However, the blog article doesn't write anything regarding the deletion, so I tried deleting it via `sudo rm -rf`, but it got the `Operation not permitted` error.

So far, I tried many answers to how to delete a file with the same error, but nothing worked in my case:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370255/as-root-cannot-remove-file-under-tmp-operation-not-permitted
- [Changing Ownership: "Operation not permitted" - even as root!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675296/changing-ownership-operation-not-permitted-even-as-root)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29902/unable-to-delete-file-even-when-running-as-root

, which include:

- change the permission of both the swapfile and the root directory `/` (`hmod ugo+w .`)
- change the immutable flag on both the swapfile and `/` (`chattr -i -a .`)
- reboot the system

All of them didn't work. I wonder how I can delete it, but if it is a swap file, how can I delete it?

The result of `free -h` is:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available 
Mem:           1.7G        101M        405M        1.2M        1.2G        1.4G
Swap:          1.5G        234M        1.3G
```

Comment: Is the swapfile still online?  Please enter the command `free -h` and append the results of that into your question.

Comment: So, the swap file is still being used by the swap process.  Please execute the command `sudo swapoff -a` and then try to delete the swapfile.

Comment: @CharlesGreen It worked! Thanks. Could you consider adding it as an answer? I'll give you +25 rep.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The output of `free -h` indicates that swap is being used - the swap process is still running.

Enter the command

```
sudo swapoff /path/to/swapfile/to/be/deleted
```

This will disable the swapfile, and the file can be deleted at that point.

Please note that if you have created an entry in `/etc/fstab` for the swapfile, you should also delete it (or comment it out by adding <kbd>#</kbd> at the beginning of the line).

Comment: Thanks. Why is the last step needed?

Comment: Part of the tutorial you were looking at earlier instructed you in how to add the swapfile to your fstab, so that it would be mounted at boot time.   I am unsure what would happen if you were to start your computer, and it tried to mount a  non-existant file.  I assume it would simply generate an error, but I'd rather not test it.

Comment: fyi: the # turns the line into a comment; allowing easy restoration if you later decide you want it, but is ignored by the system...

Comment: Why disable all swapfiles just to remove one? You can just do `sudo swapoff /path/to/swapfile/to/be/deleted` without removing any other.

Comment: @Ruslan If I had been smart enough to ask the OP to run `swapon --show` prior to answering, this would have been a great idea.

Comment: If the system tries to mount a swap-partition via fstab and the partition does not exist, it will increase boot-time by 90 seconds, this is my experience. System will still boot. I had the problem due to a changed UUID and during boot I could see a timer counting down from 1min 30sec.

Answer (score 3):

Run the following commands to delete the swap file:

```
sudo swapoff -a -v
sudo rm /swapfile
#back up /etc/fstab:
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak
sudo sed -i '/\/swapfile/d' /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate last line (i.e. `sudo sed -i '/\/swapfile/d' /etc/fstab`) of suggested commands what does it exactly do? Thank you in advance.