# Oversized swapfile preventing boot into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, swap

Running Ubuntu 18.04 without issue, the system started getting sluggish last evening before eventually starting to throw lack of memory errors running simple commands (eg, `cd`) on the command line.

I tried restarting expecting it would clear temporary memory, but haven't been able to get back into the system.  Assorted attempts to turn swap off and on again, running `fsck` to check for errors, as well as `clear` and `dpkg` within recovery mode didn't fix the issue.

I'm wondering if there's any downside to simply [deleting the swapfile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969296/how-to-delete-a-swap-file-in-ubuntu) in question (picture of the offending taken via recovery terminal below), and recreating to deal with the issue?  Any suggestions on addressing this otherwise.

I have access to recovery mode as well as an openSUSE live disk (from which I'm currently working) to effect changes.

[image]

Comment: 2GB is not "oversized" for a swap file. What makes you think this is causing the problem? But yes, you can delete the swapfile, but remember to update the respective `/etc/fstab` entry accordingly. Having partitions (or a swap file) configured there which no longer exists (or has a changed identifier) will prevent your system from booting too.

Comment: @ByteCommander, suppose I deduced after getting the OOM errors and when running the above and seeing the swpafile as a seemingly primary offender.  any better method for determining what the actual offender is if not swap?

Comment: Can you add the output of `df -h` to show how full the mounted partitions are? If e.g. /tmp or your root partition runs full that might cause similar error messages, and it could persist across reboots (in case of /tmp at least if it is not mounted as tmpfs). Swap should not show any persistent behaviour.

Comment: @ByteCommander, was able to check the offending directory (of which swap was a part) within recovery using `du` and eventually tracked down a few larger files I could delete to make sufficient space for boot.  good to go now, thank you.

Comment: It's better to use zram or zswap than a swap partition/file. You should use zram instead and maybe keep a small swap partition with lower priority. [RAM alternative to swap partion or swap file on an SSD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/360654/44425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to our discussion in comments, it seems like the issue was a full disk.

Using `df -h` and `du`, it was possible to identify some large unnecessary files and delete them to free up enough space to boot.

Comment: actually, to put an even finer point on it, running this was what allowed me to track down offending files.  `du -a /home | sort -n -r | head -n 10` where /home is the directory to be inspected