# Getting Operation not permitted error while deleting Swap file

Tags: server, permissions, swap

I am trying to delete the swap file by the following link: 
[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/delete-swap-file][1]](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/delete-swap-file%5D%5B1%5D)

However, when I type:

```
sudo rm /swapfile
```

I am getting the following error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'swapfile': Operation not permitted
```

I have changed the permissions on the swap file to 777 and I believe I have root privileges, But still not able to delete it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a swap file in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969296/how-to-delete-a-swap-file-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

```
chattr -R -ia /swapfile
```

then try...