# Can't change ownership of mounted device

Tags: permissions, mount, chown

I have mounted a usb drive on my computer. I want to change the owner to myself so that I can have an easier time writing/reading and allowing other programs to do the same. However, when I run this code:

```
sudo chown <username>:<username> -R <Drive Name>
```

It returns this:

```
chown: changing ownership of '<Drive Name>': Operation not permitted
```

I read on [This Forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675296/changing-ownership-operation-not-permitted-even-as-root) that I should run `sudo chattr -i file`

However that returns this:

```
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on <Device Name>
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is typical for partitions with a Microsoft file system, NTFS, FAT32 and exFAT. The ownership and permissions are set when mounting and cannot be modified without unmounting and mounting again, this time with new settings.

See this link with more details,

[How do I use 'chmod' on an NTFS (or FAT32) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072)

Comment: @MartinEldredge, You are welcome, I'm glad I could help :-)