# Trying to change owner of partition as su but get "Operation not permitted"

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, chmod

I'm new to ubuntu so perhaps these questions are naive. I have a partition I would like to write to so I'm trying to change the ownership of to me. I've typed:

```
    sudo chown <my username> /mnt/nvme0n1p3
```

The result is "Operation not permitted". How can it be that operation is not permitted when I used sudo? I've also tried to change ownership to ":admin". In addition, tried:

```
    sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/nvme0n1p3
```

and

```
    sudo chmod -R -v 777 *
```

from /mnt/nvme0n1p3 out of desperation. I don't get an error message when I do this but I still can't write to the partition. I get "Permission denied" when I try to drag a file to it in the GUI. I've also tried:

```
    sudo chmod ugo+wx /mnt/nvme0n1p3
```

but no luck. I've repeated with /dev in place of /mnt. I'm not sure if it's related but when I mount other partitions I can't get it to show up in the GUI. When I try,for example

```
    sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt
```

it works but then when I go to to /mnt in the GUI there's nothing there. It even makes nvme0n1p3 disapear. I've also tried:
        sudo chattr -i /mnt/nvme0n1p3
but get the error "chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on /mnt/nvme0n1p3".  What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Ownership: "Operation not permitted" - even as root!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675296/changing-ownership-operation-not-permitted-even-as-root)

Comment: Thanks. I actually have two partitions I'm have issues with. This answer fixed one of them but not the other. I've edited the end of my question to reflect this update.