# "You are not the owner" after upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 BIOS to 20.04 UEFI

Tags: uefi, 20.04, root, bios, chown

I wanted to convert a Ubuntu 18.04 BIOS to Ubuntu 20.04 UEFI. To do this in (what I thought was) the most efficient approach, I physically removed the secondary storage SSD and used the option to "wipe and install" Ubuntu 20.04. This process worked with one exception:

After physically reinstalling and mounting the secondary storage SSD, I am able to read it but do not have write privileges. I have subsequently tried to take ownership as root to no avail:

```
sudo -s
chown -R username /storage
```

Executing the preceding lines of code recursively prints `Operation not permitted` to the terminal.

Looking for recommendations to restore full ownership of this secondary storage drive without having to back it up, reformat it, and then transfer all of my content back.

Thank you!

Comment: /storage is not a standard mount location? Did you mount yourself? With what options? What is the file system of the mounted device?

Comment: Also see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675296/changing-ownership-operation-not-permitted-even-as-root).

Comment: Did you use the same user name? Is that the first user or 1000 as second user is 1001 etc. You should be able to reset ownership & permissions if ext4. If NTFS, it is how you mount it. Change to partition on SSD and run this: `ls -l` or `ll` (el, not eye.). See commands on ownership: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, the solution was to re-mount the disk specifying `uid=1000` in `/etc/fstab`.